# Vue scss style loads fails with mocamapck

Tags: vue.js, webpack, node-sass, sass-loader, mochapack

I'm having a problem when unit testing a vue single file component with some scss styling, as it is unable to process the @import statements. It works when I run launch the app using `yarn run dev` or build for production `yarn run build`, issue is only with unit test mode, and my setup uses `mochapack` to run the webpack before executing the test.

```
 WEBPACK  Compiling...

  [=========================] 98% (after emitting)

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

 error  in ./src/components/WorkTrigger.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import 'themes/default/variables';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  home/xxxxx/src/styles/main.scss 1:9  @import
  /home/xxxxx/src/components/WorkTrigger.vue 39:9                                             root stylesheet

 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/WorkTrigger.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-442
 @ ./src/components/WorkTrigger.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/components/WorkTrigger.vue
 @ ./tests/unit/WorkTrigger.spec.ts
 @ ./node_modules/mochapack/lib/entry.js

Type checking in progress...
  [=========================] 100% (completed)

 WEBPACK  Failed to compile with 1 error(s)

Error in ./src/components/WorkTrigger.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
  SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
    ╷
  1 │ @import 'themes/default/variables';
```

Any ideas on how may this be resolved. I don't need to load scss for testing, although I'm unable to disable style processing (null-loader) as I do not have a webpack.config file in the project, and I would not create one unless absolutely necessary. Project is generated with Vue CLI.

Comment: Making your path relative: `../themes/default/variables` (or `../../themes...`, if it's two levels above) should work (for both cases: app and tests).

Comment: Thank you @tao but it doesn't, tried with relative, absolute paths, none of that works!

Comment: Having same issue.

Comment: @DanielAngel I was able to fix this by prefixing the path with '~@/...', give it a try and see. Example: "@import: '~@/styles/variables'; "

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by prefixing the path with '~@/...', give it a try and see. Example: "@import: '~@/styles/variables'; "